# Change Text Content in ListView

Tags: android, listview

i am trying to change text content in ListView on click. Following is the code where i am increasing the count by 1

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
    TextView content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    String currentText = (String)content.getText();
    System.out.println(currentText.length());

    int counter=0;
    String a_letter = Character.toString(currentText.charAt(currentText.length() - 1));
    System.out.println(a_letter);
    counter = Integer.parseInt(a_letter);
    counter = counter+1;

    currentText = currentText.substring(0,currentText.length()-1);
    currentText = currentText + Integer.toString(counter);
    content.setText(currentText);

}
```

[image: See this image]

the problem is that when i click on "Caps x1" it must increase the counter of Caps but instead it increase the counter of Bricks.
What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find content view by `view.findViewByid(int id)` method as I see `fidnViewById` method is default for activity. For finding a particular item in a view, you need to do `view.FindViewbyId()`. For example in your case,

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView content = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    String currentText = (String)content.getText();
    System.out.println(currentText.length());

    int counter=0;
    String a_letter = Character.toString(currentText.charAt(currentText.length() - 1));
    System.out.println(a_letter);
    counter = Integer.parseInt(a_letter);
    counter = counter+1;

    currentText = currentText.substring(0,currentText.length()-1);
    currentText = currentText + Integer.toString(counter);
    content.setText(currentText);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some model for it. Lets say a list of items, where item has name and quantity. Then on click you should get this item by its position.
Increment quantity in model and call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.